# Kannel queue type

Tags: kannel

I have installed kannel from the rpm package kannel-sw-1.4.3.3-6.rh5u3. Have done a simple tests like sent one by one five messages("1", "2", "3", "4" and "5") to smsbox over http get for handling throttling error. From SMSC side throughput was 2 SMS per minute. I expected to get sms in following order:
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
But in kannel logs and SMPP dump I've got flow like:

```
> "1"
< ok
> "2"
< ok
> "3"
< throttling error
#first timeout less than 1 minute according config
> "4"
< throttling error
#second timeout less than 1 minute according config, but in sum with first more than 1 minute
> "5"
< ok
> "3"
< ok
> "4"
< throttling error
and so on
```

So the order in result was "1", "2", "5", "3", "4" instead of "1", "2", "3", "4", "5".
Is it possible to change order type for attempt to send last failure message instead of next one in the chain?
In documentation I found sms-incoming-queue-limit option. But I have no idea what does "Value 0 means giving strict priority to outgoing messages" mean and unfortunately I can't run the tests soon. What is strict priority and what about queue\order type?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SMPP Throttling error processing](http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/devel/2010-February/003341.html):

```
I did the following patch to smsc/smsc_smpp.c in "case submit_sm_resp:"
section from line 1609:
change
***
if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
    time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
else
    smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;

bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s",
pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,

 smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
***
to
***
if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED) {
    time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
    /* Put the message back into the SMPP queue */
    gw_prioqueue_produce(smpp->msgs_to_send, msg);
} else {
    smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;
    bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason,
octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
        smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
}
***

and in sms.c I have changed the function sms_priority_compare() to reverse
time sorting order (for some reason it was LIFO):
if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
    ret = -1;
else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
    ret = 1;
-------------- next part --------------
```

Ordering of the composite SMS parts is based on additional comparison of their `sms.id`:

```
int sms_priority_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int ret;
    Msg *msg1 = (Msg*)a, *msg2 = (Msg*)b;
    gw_assert(msg_type(msg1) == sms);
    gw_assert(msg_type(msg2) == sms);

    if (msg1->sms.priority > msg2->sms.priority)
        ret = 1;
    else if (msg1->sms.priority < msg2->sms.priority)
        ret = -1;
    else {
        if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
            ret = -1;
        else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
            ret = 1;
        else {
            if (msg1->sms.id > msg2->sms.id)
                ret = -1;
            else if (msg1->sms.id < msg2->sms.id)
                ret = 1;
            else
                ret = 0;          
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong.
Сorrect answer:

1. Change function `sms_priority_compare` in `sms.c`:

   ```
   if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
           ret = 1;
   else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
           ret = -1;
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
       ret = -1;
   else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
       ret = 1;
   else {
       if (msg1->sms.id > msg2->sms.id)
           ret = -1;
       else if (msg1->sms.id < msg2->sms.id)
           ret = 1;
       else
           ret = 0;           
   }
   ```
2. Change function `smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason` in `smsc/smsc_smpp.c`:

   ```
   static long smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason(long status)
   {
       switch(status) {
           case SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL:
           case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:
           case SMPP_ESME_RX_T_APPN:
           case SMPP_ESME_RSYSERR:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY;
               break;

           default:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_REJECTED;
       }
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   static long smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason(long status)
   {
       switch(status) {
           case SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL:
           case SMPP_ESME_RX_T_APPN:
           case SMPP_ESME_RSYSERR:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY;
               break;

           case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:
               return SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED;
               break;

           default:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_REJECTED;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Change function `handle_pdu` in `smsc/smsc_smpp.c` (`case submit_sm_resp:`):

   ```
   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
           time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
   else
           smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;    

   bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
                                       smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
           time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
   else
           smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;    

   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL)
           time(&msg->sms.time);    

   bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
                                       smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
   ```
4. Change function `bb_smscconn_send_failed` in `bb_smscconn.c`:

   ```
          case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_SHUTDOWN:
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;
   ```

   to

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;

   case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:   
          gwlist_insert(outgoing_sms, 0, sms);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_SHUTDOWN:
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;
   ```
5. Change function `handle_split` in `bb_smscconn.c`:

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, msg);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_DISCARDED:
   ```

   to

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, msg);
          break;

   case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:   
          gwlist_insert(outgoing_sms, 0, msg);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_DISCARDED:
   ```